# My opencart v3.0.2 website stopped loading

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-3

I have made some editing and suddently my website stopped working. I removed the "breadcrumbs" and left column navigation by commenting them out in the twig files.

Example of editing:

```
<!--<ul class="breadcrumb">
{% for breadcrumb in breadcrumbs %}
<li><a href="{{ breadcrumb.href }}">{{ breadcrumb.text }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>-->
```

and:

```
<div class="row"><!--{{ column_left }}-->
{% if column_left and column_right %}
{% set class = 'col-sm-6' %}
{% elseif column_left or column_right %}
```

etc

## My error in Google Chrome when trying to load page is this:

This page isn’t working
website.ro is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

## My error_log looks like this:

[10-Apr-2018 06:02:15 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Twig_Error_Loader' with message 'Unable to find template "common/column_left.twig" (looked into: /home/website/catalog/view/theme).' in /home/website/system/library/template/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php:215

Stack trace:

.0 /home/website/system/library/template/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php(139): Twig_Loader_Filesystem->findTemplate('common/column_l...')

.1 /home/website/system/library/template/Twig/Environment.php(312): Twig_Loader_Filesystem->getCacheKey('common/column_l...')

.2 /home/website/system/library/template/Twig/Environment.php(378): Twig_Environment->getTemplateClass('common/column_l...', NULL)

.3 /home/website/system/library/template/twig.php(33): Twig_Environment->loadTemplate('common/column_l...')

.4 /home/website/system/library/template.php(51): Template\Twig->render('common/column_l...', '1')

.5 /home/website/system/engine/loader.php(125): Template->render('common/column_l...', '1')

.6 /home/ in /home/website/system/library/template/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php on line 215

## Please help :)

Comment: did you delete column_left.twig file too?

Comment: No, the file exist at path: home/website/catalog/view/theme/default/template/common. I can see that the path has an extra "default" folder, but I didn't made any editing in path, files, folders, etc.

Comment: Please check which theme is active right now. go to admin > extensions > extensions > select themes > Edit it > which theme is selected in theme directory?

Comment: I didn't installed any theme, is the default theme.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48423908. This can be helpful to you.

Comment: Thank's a lot, it works!